# Android Enthusiasts SE content appearing on random sites. Is this allowed?

Tags: discussion, support

Recently, while I was surfing the web and researching for some information for my Tasker projects, I bumped onto one of my old posts (that I posted on [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com)) which left me wondering how this post had found its way onto random sites with exactly the same content?

I had posted the question; [Automatically disable mobile hotspot when no device is connected, using Tasker](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/170790/209414), but later found the question on these sites:

1. http://eadiscussion.com/index.php?threads/automatically-disable-mobile-hotspot-when-no-device-is-connected-using-tasker.7490/#post-7490
2. https://tutel.me/c/android/questions/170790/automatically+disable+mobile+hotspot+when+no+device+is+connected+using+tasker

to mention a few...

My question is, is this kind of behavior allowed or **has Stack Exchange given permission to such sites in order to republish the  content?** To my surprise there is even no referral link to the SE site from where the content was extracted and also the sites have no convincing detail that reveal their affiliation with SE (if any)?

Please note that I have no problem with people using my information on thier websites, but I am a bit amused as to why this information is appearing on the sites **as if they a sub-sites to Android SE**, and even more funnier they also have a tags :)

Comment: This is covered on the SE meta in this question: [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/222389)

Comment: @DanHulme Actually an exact dupe. The MSE post you linked has all the things covered.

Comment: I apologise for duplicate, it wasn't intended, had not encountered that post before